# Quick thought regarding .split()

Tags: python, genetics

So I need to make a punnett square using python. A punnett square is basically a simple method of determining visible and sometimes non-visible traits. My code so far takes the two parent's genetic makeup and finds all the different combinations of A's and G's. The only problem I am having at this point is that when I print, the letters aren't in the correct order. For example: for each "child's" possible genetic makeup, there are two A's (either capital or lowercase) and two G's ( also either upper or lowercase). I have done a fair amount of research and the only other question/answer on SOF that was somewhat related to mine was not clear and didn't work. My code is as follows.

```
import itertools
import string

#genepool_1 refers to parent 1's alleles
#genepool_2 refers to parent 2's alleles
#outerlayerf1 refers to both parent genetic contributions to the first generation of offspring
#f1 refers to the punnett square of the first generation of offspring

#parent 1
genepool_1 = ['Aa','Gg']
parent_1 = sorted(list(itertools.product(*genepool_1)))

#parent 2
genepool_2 = ['aa','GG']
parent_2 = sorted(list(itertools.product(*genepool_2)))


#F1 or Parent 1/2 Offspring
outerlayerf1 = [parent_1,parent_2]
f1___________ = list(itertools.product(*outerlayerf1))
f1__________ = str(f1___________)
f1_________ = f1__________.replace('[','')
f1________ = f1_________.replace(']','')
f1_______ = f1________.replace("'",'')
f1______ = f1_______.replace(' ','')
f1_____ = f1______.replace(')),((', ') (')
f1____ = f1_____.replace('((', '(')
f1___ = f1____.replace('))',')')
f1__ = f1___.replace('),(','')
f1_ = f1__.replace(',','')
print f1_
```

And it prints out

```
(AGaG) (AGaG) (AGaG) (AGaG) (AgaG) (AgaG) (AgaG) (AgaG) (aGaG) (aGaG) (aGaG) (aGaG) (agaG) (agaG) (agaG) (agaG)
```

When it *should* print

```
(AaGG) (AaGG) (AaGG) (AaGG) (AagG) (AagG) (AagG) (AagG) (aaGG) (aaGG) (aaGG) (aaGG) (aagG) (aagG) (aagG) (aagG)
```

(*I am aware that each option is printed 4 times. It needs to be this way to have the most accurate probabilities*)

Thanks *so* much,

Eli

Comment: That is some strange variable naming convention

Comment: Haha yes I know I couldn't think of anything better and the underscores just grew in numbers @PadraicCunningham

Comment: maybe `f_1, f_2`  or `f1_1, f1_2` .. might be a little easier to follow ;)

Comment: what's with all the calls to `sorted(list(iterator))`? Sorted returns a list.....

Comment: or just leave it as a list....

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes but if I did that then it would be more cofusing. See, with punnett squares, F1 refers to the first generation of offspring, F2 refers to the second generation, and so on. I figured that since I was just using those variables for replacing, it didn't matter what their name was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am horribly confused by everything related to this question, but I think I got it to work with this, so at least I hope that helps:

```
f1 = [
     thingies[0][0] + thingies[1][0] + thingies[0][1] + thingies[1][1]
     for thingies in zip(parent_1, parent_2)
] * 4
print(f1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get it using `zip()` function and `str.jon()` -

```
>>> genepool_1 = ['Aa','Gg']
>>> parent_1 = sorted(list(itertools.product(*genepool_1)))
>>>
>>> #parent 2
... genepool_2 = ['aa','GG']
>>> parent_2 = sorted(list(itertools.product(*genepool_2)))
>>>
>>>
>>> #F1 or Parent 1/2 Offspring
... outerlayerf1 = [parent_1,parent_2]
>>> f1 = list(itertools.product(*outerlayerf1))
>>> f2 = [''.join(''.join(i) for i in list(zip(*x))) for x in f1]
['AaGG', 'AaGG', 'AaGG', 'AaGG', 'AagG', 'AagG', 'AagG', 'AagG', 'aaGG', 'aaGG', 'aaGG', 'aaGG', 'aagG', 'aagG', 'aagG', 'aagG']
```